# What is the for(;;){ } syntax?

Tags: java

I've seen in a java program the following syntax :

```
for(;;){

}
```

What does it means ? I didn't see the explanation on internet after some researches.

Is it the same thing that a while(true) loop?

**Edit :**

Sorry for duplicate, when your type " for(;;) " in your researches you doesn't find the information wanted. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Were you not able to verify this?

Comment: I never understood the existence of this while `while(true)` exists. Well, it's just me.

Comment: @PLB, the while(true) (in C/C++: while(1)) is usefull for something that has to run "infinitely". The actual interruption of the loop in such cases is handled in its body. Low-level example: imagine you have a microcontoller that once powered on has to run and run, checking input from its pins and sending signals to other parts of the system. There are situation in high-level programming languages (such as Java) where something like this is also needed: waiting for input by the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
for (;;) {
}
```

It's a shorthand for an infinite loop, equivalent to this:

```
while (true) {
}
```

In fact, as show in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880898/201359) both are completely equivalent at the bytecode level.

Answer (score 1):

The three expressions of the `for` loop are optional.

an infinite loop can be created as follows:

// infinite loop

```
for ( ; ; ) {

    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an infinite loop and yes, it is the same as

```
while(true) {

}
```

But considering the complexity" of your question I do believe you could have just written a simple Hello World programm with this structure in it and see what happen, right? ;)