# calculate minimum value from user input while excluding loop termination number (-1)

Tags: java

Hey I'm trying to work out the minimum and maximum value from user input while disregarding the loop terminated value, which is -1. I understand how to do everything except how to disregard -1 when calculating minimum value for the input.
Here's the code I've got so far:

```
    int value = 0;
    int max = value;
    int min = max;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (value != -1) {
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        value = scan.nextInt();
        if (min > value) {
        min = value;     }

       if (max < value) {
           max = value; }
    }

    System.out.println("Min = " + min);
    System.out.println("Min = " + min);
```

How can I calculate the minimum value while disregarding -1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turn the loop into a never-ending loop, and add a `break` when termination number is detected:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (;;) { // never-ending loop
    System.out.print("Value: ");
    if (! scan.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("** Invalid input **");
        scan.nextLine(); // discard invalid input
        continue; // loop back to prompt again
    }
    int value = scan.nextInt();
    if (value == -1) // termination number
        break;
    if (value < min)
        min = value;
    else if (value > max)
        max = value;
}
System.out.println("Min = " + min);
System.out.println("Max = " + max);
```

Also fixed:

- Initialization of `min` and `max` (otherwise `min` will likely always be `0`)
- Validation of `Scanner` input (so program doesn't die with exception on bad input)
- Printing of `max` (was printing `min` twice)
- Indentation (so code structure is clearly visible to human readers)

Comment: any reason you use an empty for loop instead of a while(true) loop? I've seen both idioms and always figured it's probably just programmer preference.

Comment: @AustinD It is entirely programmer preference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue

Answer (score 0):

Add `if (value == -1) break;` right before the line that starts with`if (min > value)`. This causes the loop to break once the terminal (-1) character is read.

For clarity, you can then change your loop condition to `while(true)`. This is a pretty common idiom for this situation.