# Peculiar for loop - for(;;){} - in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Hi Stackoverflow Community

I came across the following for loop in the following Java documentation ([Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)) earlier today and was wondering whether anyone would be able to elaborate what the ";;" - loop condition means?

Here the code-snipped I am talking about (full code provided below):

```
public void run() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (;;) {
       try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        bowee.bow(bower);
    }
}
```

Here the entire code example:

```js
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Random;

public class Safelock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
            Boolean myLock = false;
            Boolean yourLock = false;
            try {
                myLock = lock.tryLock();
                yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
            } finally {
                if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                    if (myLock) {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                    if (yourLock) {
                        bower.lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
            return myLock && yourLock;
        }
            
        public void bow(Friend bower) {
            if (impendingBow(bower)) {
                try {
                    System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                        + " bowed to me!%n", 
                        this.name, bower.getName());
                    bower.bowBack(this);
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                    + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                    + " I was already bowing to"
                    + " him.%n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
            }
        }

        public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has" +
                " bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    static class BowLoop implements Runnable {
        private Friend bower;
        private Friend bowee;

        public BowLoop(Friend bower, Friend bowee) {
            this.bower = bower;
            this.bowee = bowee;
        }
    
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                bowee.bow(bower);
            }
        }
    }
            

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new BowLoop(alphonse, gaston)).start();
        new Thread(new BowLoop(gaston, alphonse)).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just means 'loop forever'

Comment: `for (;;)` is an infinite loop, exactly the same as `while (true)`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue/8880898#8880898).

Comment: There is no ";;" condition. As many tutorials explain a `for` loop header consists of three parts delimited by a single `;`. So what could it mean when where are two of them and nothing else?

Comment: Sorry that was the c## dup, here's the correct one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880870/java-for-vs-whiletrue

Comment: @Tom https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @pvg I know what a for loop is.

Comment: @Tom very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

> The three expressions of the for loop are optional; an infinite loop
>   can be created as follows:
>
> ```
> // infinite loop
> for ( ; ; ) {
>
>     // your code goes here
> }
> ```

Please at least google the documentation before posting.

Comment: Please at least look for a duplicate before answering.

Comment: I suppose I deserved that.

Comment: Hi @Overt_Agent. Thank you for this. I did in fact Google it and was unable to locate any definitive resources. Therefore appreciate the info :). Thanks.