# please explain, Why the below code is going to infinite loop

Tags: java

Why below code is going for infinite loop? Why is it not throwing compile time error?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       for(;;){
           System.out.println("while loop");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's legal code, and it expresses an infinite loop.

Comment: The for loop iteration stops once the condtion (after first ; in for loop) is not satisfied. In the above Code there is no Condition to statisfy and is true by default. So this code will run as a infinite loop.

Comment: See also [Java: for(;;) vs. while(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8880870), and why some people prefer it https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611529 (although this answer is based on C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax of a basic for loop is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> ```
> BasicForStatement:
>     for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
> ```

The `[]` around `ForInit`, `Expression` and `ForUpdate` mean that all of those things are optional.

As such, `for (;;) { /* something */ }` is valid syntax, so it would not result in a compile-time error.

Then (emphasis added):

> **If the Expression is not present**, or it is present and the value
>   resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is
>   true, **then the contained Statement is executed**. Then there is a
>   choice:
>
> 1. If execution of the Statement completes normally, then the following
>      two steps are performed in sequence:
>
>    - First, if the ForUpdate part is present [it's not, so omitting this]
>
>      **If the ForUpdate part is not present, no action is taken**.
>    - Second, **another for iteration step is performed**.

`Expression` is not present, the `Statement` completes normally: so another for iteration step is performed.

This is all a way of saying: you've got an infinite loop because there's nothing to stop it continuing to execute.